# Why this EntityManager Query doesn't return anything?

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, query-builder

I have a User entity and a HistoryAccess entity that binds two User instances as follows: a user specified in it as "allowed" can get a user specified as "owner".

I am trying to make a query that will receive the data of all users available to the current user. Query code:

```
$user = $security->getUser();
$userId = $user->getId()->toRfc4122();

return $entityManager->createQueryBuilder()
    ->from('App\Entity\User', 'u')
    ->join('u.ownerHistoryAccesses', 'ha')
    ->join('ha.allowed', 'a')
    ->where('a.id = :currentUserId')
    ->setParameter('currentUserId', $userId)
    ->select('u, ha, a.id')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getArrayResult();
```

But this query does not return anything

If I delete the andWhere and setParameter lines, the result is the expected dataset, with a.id being the same identifier as the $userId value. Why doesn’t the request with the andWhere and setParameter return anything?

Comment: Does it work if you remove the `select` call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not in the query, but in the ID format. The database did not store RFC4122, but a binary format. So I had to replace `toRfc4122()` with `toBinary()`